# Is it possible to have a cronjob to keep running an SQL query where multiple rows match in same table?

Tags: php, cron, match, matching

I have two tables, 'pendingresults' and 'confirmedresults' 
For a football site I am trying to create a report score page which allows two users with a team to report a score against each other after they have played, as an example i'll use team1 and team2..

So lets say team1 beat team2, 3 goals to 1 (3-1) the manager of team1 would goto his reportscore page and insert the score and select that he had played team2, a query of this would put the results into the 'pendingresults' table which contains:

```
      id, TeamA, TeamAScore, TeamBScore, TeamB
```

so team1 adds the score and the query is successful so now the pendingresults table looks a little like this:

```
        id  TeamA     TeamAScore  TeamBScore  TeamB
         1   team1        3           1        team2
```

I have the above coded and working..

What I need help with is once team2 reports the score as a 3-1 loss, the pendingresults table will have two of the exact same rows (other than the id), how would i make it so that every few hours something like a cronjob runs to check if two rows match then make a query run to insert the teams and scores into the 'confirmedresults' table, which has the exact same columns as 'pendingresults' and then delete the two rows from the pendingresults table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest another approach:

If a team manager A wants to enter the results, your script first checks whether the other team's manager B already entered results. If this is the case, A simply confirms or corrects the results entered by B.

With your approach and a typo in the scores by either A or B, you will not get a match (of the records) at all.

Just to improve this idea further, you simply have one table called `results` with an additional column `confirmed`. If A enters the results, you set "A" to `confirmed`. If B they does not agree and updates the scores, you set "B" to `confirmed`. A then checks and agrees, so you set "AB" to `confirmed`.

All `results` with `confirmed` set to "AB" then are confirmed match results all others are pending/unconfirmed match results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Is there anywhere i can find an example script because i am not totally sure how i would allow each manager to see scores reported against them. And the confirmedresults table updates the league table.